# delay in response of geocoder.geocode causing trouble

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am calculating latitude,longitude of all addresses of country i have in mysql DB using geocoder.geocode. I calculate lat,long successfully, even calculate the distance from my lat,long to all addresses lat,long and stored those distances in an array. but when i access the array it is empty, and console.log is printing all contents of array.

```
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLatLon, showError);
     }else{
     console.log("Geo Location is not supported");
   }

function getLatLon(position){
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lng = position.coords.longitude;
var country;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        country = results[7].address_components[0].long_name;
        $.ajax({
          url:"getLocations.php",
          method:"POST",
          dataType:"JSON",
          data:{location:country},
          success: function(data){
            var i=0;
            var length = data.length;
            for(i;i<length;i++){
              if(isNaN(data[i])){
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var address = data[i];
                var distance = getDistance(address,latlng,data[i+1]);
                // myLocations.push(distance);
              }

            }
// This console.log prints all data
            console.log(myLocations);            
// But this piece of code is not working
            for(var iterations=0;iterations<myLocations.length;iterations++){
              console.log(myLocations[iterations]);
             }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

function getDistance(address,latlng,index){
  var distance;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                  {
                    var newdata = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    distance = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(newdata, latlng))*0.000621371;
                    var var1 = {distance: distance, index:index};
                    myLocations.push(var1);
                  }
                });
return distance;
}

  function showError(error){
      switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          var img = $('.arrow');
          img.css('display','none');
          console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          var img = $('.arrow');
          img.css('display','none');
      console.log("Location information is unavailable.");
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
          var img = $('.arrow');
          img.css('display','none');
      console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          var img = $('.arrow');
          img.css('display','none');
      console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
      break;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

may be it work for some one else, I used `setTimeout(function(){ alert(myLocations); }, 3000);` after page load and it printed out the entire array as i wanted.